# Move all Docker stuff?

Tags: docker, digital-ocean

I own a 5$ 20GB SSD Digital Ocean droplet and it almost run out of space with docker images and containers.

Is there any way to buy a volume, attach it to the server and safely move all the docker stuff right there?

Comment: See https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3127

Comment: Hello, did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes I did. Sorry for a late reply. 
I followed all the guidelines I've found before and can't do it. The problem was in systemd daemon. It also needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can attach a new volume and copy `/var/lib/docker` content into it. Then mount your new volume there.

Remember stopping the docker daemon first

Regards